# Objective C why are the objects from my NSMutableArray disappearing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS. I'm having trouble with something that is probably easily corrected, but I have no idea why it's happening.

I'll try to give a brief description of what I'm doing and hopefully it'll have enough info to spot the error.

PolygonView.h is a UIView type class, and it declares the NSmutablearray like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *polys;
```

I init it in PolygonView.m's initWithFrame:(CGRect)Frame method like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    polys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self loadCsv];
    return self;
}
```

inside loadCSV I load a csv use it to create a few poly objects and do some other stuff, but here's the gist of it:

```
poly* p;
p = [[poly alloc] init];
// here I set a few properties on p from the csv file and then add p to polys like this:
[polys addObject:p];
```

At the end of the method I use nslog to print the count like this:

```
NSLog(@"polys size = %i", [polys count]);
```

This prints "polys size = 100" on the console.

And then I decided to do my own drawRect. and the beginning of it use the same nslog to print the size/count, but "polys size = 0" is printed on the console.

What am I doing wrong? how can I access the objects I added to this array from the drawRect method?

edit:
here's the full polygonView.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PolygonView : UIView{
        NSMutableArray *polys;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *polys;

-(void)loadCSV;

@end
```

edit 2: the full polygon

```
//
//  PolygonView.m
//  Polygon2
//

#import "PolygonView.h"
#import "poly.h"


@implementation PolygonView
@synthesize polys;

-(id)init
{
    NSLog(@"regular init");

    self = [super init];
   if (self) {
        self.polys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self loadCsv];

    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"init with frame");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.polys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self loadCsv];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadCsv
{
    poly* p;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DivisoesEstaduais" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *newString = [testString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
    if (newString) {
        NSMutableArray *arrr = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [arrr count]; i++){
            if ([[arrr objectAtIndex:i] length] > 0){
                p = [[poly alloc] init];
                NSMutableArray *arrayatual = [[arrr objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
                [p setPolyid:[arrayatual objectAtIndex:0]];
                [p setPartid:[arrayatual objectAtIndex:1]];
                [p setPointid:[arrayatual objectAtIndex:2]];
                [p setx:[arrayatual objectAtIndex:3]];
                [p sety:[arrayatual objectAtIndex:4]];
                [self.polys addObject:p];
                NSLog(@"polys size = %i", [self.polys count]); // this increases from 1 to 100
            }  
        }
        NSLog(@"polys size = %i", [self.polys count]); // this prints 100
    }else{
        NSLog(@"not");
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    srandom( time( NULL ) );
    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, random() % 250, random() % 250, random() % 250, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    int oldtemp = 0;
    NSLog(@"drawRect polys pointer = %@", self.polys); // this is null
    NSLog(@"polys size = %i", [self.polys count]); // this is zero
    for (int i = 0; i < [polys count]; i++){
        poly *p = [polys objectAtIndex:i];
        int temp = p.getPolyid.intValue;
        if (temp == oldtemp){
            CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
            CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
            CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
            UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
            CGContextFillPath(context);
            NSLog(@"movetopoint");
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, [p.getx floatValue]+160, [p.gety floatValue]+160);
            oldtemp++;
        }else{
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [p.getx floatValue]+160, [p.gety floatValue]+160);
            NSLog(@"addlinetopoint");
        }
    }

    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
   UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
 }

@end
```

and here's viewController.m:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Polygon2
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    PolygonView * pv = [[PolygonView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:pv];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Edit3:

George Sachin's solution worked: use viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. But why was viewDidLoad causing me trouble? Here's the zipped project in case anyone wants to take a look and try to figure out.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/b9ueqkqbmxswd7a/Polygon2_3.zip

Seems to me ViewDidload is the one I should be using. Should I never use it?

Comment: well my guess is that polys is nil when you ask the time that it reports 0... sending any method to nil will return a zero (the appropriate size and kind of zero)

Comment: The objects wouldn't just disappear, but the array would.

Comment: Why does that happen? how can I access the objects I added do it during the LoadCSV method?

Comment: Most likely you are referring to a DIFFERENT `polys` pointer, maybe in a different object.  NSLog `polys` itself vs it count, and you will likely see that it's nil (vs an empty array that will print as `()`).

Comment: this is going to be hard without seeing exactly what code is being used between all of your methods. I know you're saying that you did a copy/paste of some code but the problem might be a "you can't see the forest for the trees" issue.

Comment: You should probably just include all the code for the class, it's hard to know for sure with just the code provided, based on what you posted seems like @HotLicks is correct

Comment: indeed polys is null when I try to access it from drawRect. Why did that happen?

Comment: Most likely you have two instances of your object, and you're creating the array in one and accessing it in the other.  Simply having two identical objects does not make values magically jump from one to the other.

Comment: can you see exactly where the array goes to NULL when you debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Edit:**

When you create an initializer for a UIView you should **always** call super's initWithFrame: or initWithCoder: when you use a .xib

Change your code to this:

```
-(id)init
{
NSLog(@"regular init");

self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)]; // Replace with the dimensions you want
if (self) {
    self.polys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self loadCsv];

}
NSLog(@"(init)polys size = %i", [self.polys count]); 

return self;
}
```

Comment: I tried using self.polys when I init/alloc it, when I add (like this[self.polys addObject:p];  ) and when I print the size/count on drawRect. still getting a 0 count.

Comment: yes, everywhere where I either initialise it, print the count or add objects to it.

Comment: What happens if you NSLog(@"%d",[self.polys count]) exactly below the line [self.polys addObject:p]; ??

Comment: Note also that your `polys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` and `[self loadCsv];` lines should be **inside** the `if (self)`, right with the `// Initialization code` comment. That's the point of this test.

Comment: it's still not working.  I just added the whole polygonview.m and viewcontroller.m files as an edit to my question

Comment: NSLog the self.polys count exactly before the "return self;" to see what happens

Comment: Create a @property for the polygonView in your view controller.

Comment: like this? @property PolygonView * pv;
I then added PolygonView * pv; to viewcontroller.h's @interface and used pv = [[PolygonView alloc] init]; in m`s viewDidLoad. same error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31886/discussion-between-george-sachin-and-hsnn)

Comment: Your edit 2 worked, thanks! But I don't understand why viewDidLoad didn't work. Should I always use viewDidAppear? When should I use viewDidLoad instead of DidAppear?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

1) When you're setting `@property(nonatomic, retain) myObj` to the object you should do in the `.m` file `@synthesize myObj`

2) as HSNN says you should access it via self.myObj

3)It's better to do init part in between this part

```
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
```

phrase "initialization code" was put there not accidentally))

Most likely that root of the problem is forgotten `@synthesize` but it's better to cover all 3 steps.

good luck. feel free to ask if this won't help)

Comment: I tried a few of those things but it doesn't seem to be working. I just added the whole polygonview.m and viewcontroller.m files as an edit to my question

Comment: I think i've found the problem. in ViewController.m you're saying PolygonView alloc init, but in polygon.h you have polygonInitWithFrame. These are TWO DIFFERENT init. change init to initWithFrame and everything should work.

Comment: instead I implemented the regular init. I just edited my post to reflect the new init.
but now I noticed that both init and initwithframe are being called (added an nslog to both). LoadCSV is being called twice because of this. And self.polys in drawRect is still null. I did not change anything in viewcontroller.

Comment: Please could you comment init with frame and check nslog's is draw recit being called after polys is full with data?